# How to send image and text at the same time using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I want send this Postdata and imagefile at the same time using retrofit.

**PostData** and **Point**

```
public class PostData implements Serializable {
    @Expose
    private String text;
    @Expose
    private Point point;
}
public class Point implements Serializable {
    @Expose
    private double longitude;
    @Expose
    private double latitude;
}
```

**PostApiService**

```
public interface PostApiService {

    @Multipart
    @POST("posts/")
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadFile (@Part MultipartBody.Part part, @Body PostData postData);
}
```

I get image uri out of these codes, and i will use it. It used as returnUri.
You may consider this.

**CODE :**

```
view.findViewById(R.id.btn_post).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void PostImageAndData(View view) {

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = getBitmapFromUri(returnUri); #this method is to make Bitmap from Uri
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        File imageFile = null;
        try {
            imageFile = createFileFromBitmap(bitmap); #this method is to make File from Bitmap
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        client = builder.build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(Constants.HTTP.BASE_URL)
                .build();

        PostApiService postApiService = retrofit.create(PostApiService.class);
        RequestBody requestFile =
                RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), imageFile);
        MultipartBody.Part body =
                MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", makeImageFileName(), requestFile); #this method(makeimageFileName()) is for custom filename 
        Point mpoint = new Point(13, 15);
        PostData postData = new PostData("hello", mpoint);

        Call<ResponseBody> call = postApiService.uploadFile(body, postData);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "success?", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
    }
});
```

If i use `@Body PostData postData` on PostApiService, Error is `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding. (parameter #2)`

and If i use `@Part PostData postData` on PostApiService, Error is `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Part annotation must supply a name or use MultipartBody.Part parameter type. (parameter #2)`

So, What should i do?

Please, Would you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yesterday i had same problem and i have solved it.

It directly said two different format is not allowed.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding. (parameter #2)

You need to send all data in form of **Part** only.

```
@Multipart
@POST("/api/Accounts/editaccount")
Call<User> editUser (@Part("Authorization") String authorization,@Part("file\"; filename=\"pp.png\" ") RequestBody file , @Part("FirstName") RequestBody fname, @Part("Id") RequestBody id);
```

Something like this.

Thanks hope this help you.

Comment: retrofit2 is much harder to use for me, than i predicted. Thank you. Saveen

Comment: Yes me too till yesterday :) Don't worry

Comment: @Saveen i need your in here ...facing problem in multipart thing --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63149093/how-do-i-post-long-encoded-string-of-base64-image-to-server-using-retrofit