# Retrofit 2.0.2 image upload using multipart

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am new for Retrofit **I wanna to upload single image with different params like name,dob,mobile.** i don't know where i am wrong Please guide me. I follow this **[LINK](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server)**

Here is my code

**interface**

```
 @Multipart
    @POST("signup")
    Call<ResponseBody> getSignup(@Part("name") RequestBody name, @Part("email") RequestBody email, @Part("dob") RequestBody dob, @Part("phone") RequestBody phone, @Part("IMEI") RequestBody IMEI, @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

**upload code**

```
 // create RequestBody instance from file
                RequestBody requestFile =
                        RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

                // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
                MultipartBody.Part body =
                        MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), requestFile);

                RequestBody name =
                        RequestBody.create(
                                MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), et_name.getText().toString());

                RequestBody email =
                        RequestBody.create(
                                MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), et_email.getText().toString());

                RequestBody dob =
                        RequestBody.create(
                                MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), et_dob.getText().toString());

                RequestBody mobile =
                        RequestBody.create(
                                MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), et_mobile.getText().toString());


                RequestBody imei =
                        RequestBody.create(
                                MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), IMEI);

                Call<ResponseBody> responseBodyCall = apiInterface.getSignup(name, email, dob, mobile, imei, body);
                responseBodyCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                        String response_two = response.body().toString();

                        Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + response_two);
//                        startActivity(new Intent(this, OTPActivity.class));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.e("Upload error:", t.getMessage());
                    }
                });
```

Comment: What is your issue ?

Comment: i don't want to upload multiple file only one file i want to send.

Comment: i am not able to upload file with different params like mobile,name,imei etc..

Comment: Are you try with one image?Is this working

Comment: no i didn't try do i??

Comment: What should i change for that??

Comment: First make sure that this is not from the sever side and try to upload single one then try multiple. I can' t c any issue in the code

Comment: This will help you for that https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-multiple-files-to-server

Comment: The above link will explain about the multiple file uploading in the retrofit pls check

Comment: i just want single file upload with parameters.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562950/post-multipart-form-data-using-retrofit-2-0-including-image

Comment: try this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39558595/how-to-send-image-and-text-at-the-same-time-using-retrofit

Answer (score 1):

***Retrofit 2.0 onwards try this answer***

```
@Multipart
@POST("/service/users/add_user")
Call<AddUsersModel> addUser(@Part("user_name") RequestBody userName, @Part("user_last_name") RequestBody lastName, @Part("user_password") RequestBody password,
                               @Part("user_email") RequestBody email, @Part("user_mobile") RequestBody mobile, @Part MultipartBody.Part user_profile);
```

File path to **MulitpartBody.Part** convertion

```
   MultipartBody.Part profileImageBody = null;
        RequestBody reqFile = null;
        try {
            String filePath = CameraIntentUtil.getFIlePath();
            Log.d(TAG, "createAccount: filePath:" + filePath);
            if (filePath != null) {
                File file = new File(filePath);

                reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
                // "user_profile" is my post request key
                profileImageBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("user_profile", file.getName(), reqFile);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "createAccount: ", e);
        }
```

String to **RequestBody** convertion

```
public static RequestBody stringToRequestBody(String data) {
    return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), data);
}
```

Very late answer.. But I hope it help atleast anyone

Answer (score 0):

you need to add same type for image also see here how it work,
This is for multiple images as well.

```
@Multipart
@POST(ApiConstants.EDIT_REQUEST)
Observable<CommonModel> editRequest(@Part("requestid") RequestBody requestid, @PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody> mapFileAndName);


RequestBody requestid1 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), requestid);

Map<String, RequestBody> files = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < mList.size(); i++) {
        String key = "package_image[" + String.valueOf(i) + "]";
        files.put("" + key + "\"; filename=\"" + key + ".png", getRequestFile(new File(mList.get(i).getImagePath())));
}



private RequestBody getRequestFile(File file) {

    RequestBody fbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
    return fbody;

}
```

for more details you can visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562950/post-multipart-form-data-using-retrofit-2-0-including-image)

Answer (score 0):

its my example of POST multipart

```
@Multipart
@POST("/api/register?platform=android")
Call<Register> register(@Part("photo\"; filename=\"photoName.png\" ") RequestBody photo,
                                     @Part("name") RequestBody name,
                                     @Part("phoneNumber") RequestBody phoneNumber,
                                     @Part("password") RequestBody password,carColor,
                                     @Query("language") String language);
```

Comment: Query doesn't work in retrofit 2.0.2, only we can send part type

Comment: i have - compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2' is it different?

Comment: ahh sorry! i didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

## Tested on retrofit 2.3.0

1. Create `interface`

   ```
   @Multipart
   @POST("edit_profile")
   Call<TokenResponse> getTokenAccess(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> 
    map);
   ```
2. Call in your `Activity`

   ```
                Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
               .baseUrl(getString(R.string.api_coolpool))
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
               .build();
               File file = new File("/storage/sdcard0/Pictures/OGQ/Puskinn 
               Sharma_Jump roof skyscraper_YkRiRWpYcw.jpg");
                String convert_File_2String= String.valueOf(file);
                String fileNAme=convert_File_2String.substring(convert_File_2String.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
   RequestBody fbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
   RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "Sunil");
   RequestBody id = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "56");
   RequestBody lastname= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "Kumar");
   Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
   map.put("profile_pic\"; filename=\""+fileNAme+"\" ", fbody);
   map.put("firstname", name);
   map.put("user_id", id);
   map.put("lastname",lastname);

   Call<TokenResponse> tokenResponseCall=service.getTokenAccess(map);
   tokenResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<TokenResponse>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Call<TokenResponse> call, Response<TokenResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful())
           Log.e("Success", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
       else
           Log.e("unSuccess", new Gson().toJson(response.errorBody()));
   }

           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call<TokenResponse> call, Throwable throwable) {
           Log.e("172","><<>>"+throwable);

       }
   });
   ```