# Retrofit upload image by multi part along with other form data like name,email in android

Tags: android, retrofit, multipartform-data

I have a screen with Image View to display Profile Pic and name field. I want to POST the profile Pic using retrofit Multi Part along with name field. I have being searching the internet but didn't get any solution. Kindly help if some did it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: checkout from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40787054/retrofit-2-0-2-image-upload-using-multipart

Comment: getting exception  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.socialpixe.enhancelabs, PID: 18357 retrofit.RetrofitError at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:400)
  at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)   
                                                                                                                    Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
 at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)