# how do i post Long encoded string of base64 image to server using retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, base64, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to post encoded string of image to retrofit post method...after debugging i got very long string on debug of image chosen from gallery.....after submitting i can see long string encoded of image in debugger....in postman when i check i shows  **`profile_pic: " "`** that is null ...

If I used endpoint like this im not getting crash:

```
   @FormUrlEncoded
@POST("update")
fun useredit(
    @Header("access_token") token: String,
    @Field("first_name") first_name:String,

    @Field("last_name") last_name:String,
    @Field("email") email:String,

    @Field("dob") dob:String,
    @Field("phone_no") phone_no: String,
    @Field("profile_pic") profile_pic:String

):Call<LoginResponse>
```

response code:

```
profile = findViewById<View>(R.id.profilepic) as ImageView

    profile?.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

        val intent = Intent()
        intent.type = "image/*"
        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE)
    })
    editsubmit.setOnClickListener {

        val first_name = firstname.text.toString().trim()
        val last_name = lastname.text.toString().trim()

        val email = emailregister.text.toString().trim()
        val phone = phoneno.text.toString().trim()

        val profile =convertToString()!!
        val token: String =
            SharedPrefManager.getInstance(
                applicationContext
            ).user.access_token.toString()

        RetrofitClient.instance.useredit(token,first_name,last_name,email,edittext1.text.toString(),phone,profile)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<LoginResponse> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.d("res", "" + t)
                }
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<LoginResponse>,
                    response: Response<LoginResponse>
                ) {
                    var res = response
                    Log.d("response check ", "" + response.body()?.status.toString())
                    if (res.body()?.status==200) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            applicationContext,
                            res.body()?.message,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                        Log.d("kjsfgxhufb",response.body()?.status.toString())
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try {
                            val jObjError =
                                JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.string())
                            Toast.makeText(
                                applicationContext,
                                jObjError.getString("message")+jObjError.getString("user_msg"),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show()
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            Log.e("errorrr",e.message)
                        }
                    }

                }
            })
    }
}
private fun convertToString(): String? {
      val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream)
    val imgByte: ByteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()

    return android.util.Base64.encodeToString(imgByte, android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP )
}

override fun onActivityResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    resultCode: Int,
    data: Intent?
) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        val path: Uri? = data.data
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, path)
            profile?.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

### im seeing long string on debugger but not on postman

**Later i tried this**-->

my endpoint:

```
   @Multipart
@POST("update")
fun useredit(
    @Header("access_token") token: String,
    @Part("first_name") first_name:String,

    @Part("last_name") last_name:String,
    @Part("email") email:String,

    @Part("dob") dob:String,
    @Part("phone_no") phone_no: String,
    @Part ("profile_pic")profile_pic: MultipartBody.Part?

):Call<LoginResponse>
```

activity response code:-

```
profile?.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

        val intent = Intent()
        intent.type = "image/*"
        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE)
    })
    editsubmit.setOnClickListener {

        val first_name = firstname.text.toString().trim()
        val last_name = lastname.text.toString().trim()

        val email = emailregister.text.toString().trim()
        val phone = phoneno.text.toString().trim()

        val profile =convertToString()!!
        val token: String =
            SharedPrefManager.getInstance(
                applicationContext
            ).user.access_token.toString()
        val requestFile: RequestBody =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), profile)

        val body: MultipartBody.Part =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", "image.jpg", requestFile)
        RetrofitClient.instance.useredit(token,first_name,last_name,email,edittext1.text.toString(),phone,body)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<LoginResponse> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.d("res", "" + t)
                }
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<LoginResponse>,
                    response: Response<LoginResponse>
                ) {
                    var res = response
                    Log.d("response check ", "" + response.body()?.status.toString())
                    if (res.body()?.status==200) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            applicationContext,
                            res.body()?.message,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                        Log.d("kjsfgxhufb",response.body()?.status.toString())
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try {
                            val jObjError =
                                JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.string())
                            Toast.makeText(
                                applicationContext,
                                jObjError.getString("message")+jObjError.getString("user_msg"),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show()
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            Log.e("errorrr",e.message)
                        }
                    }

                }
            })
    }
}
private fun convertToString(): String? {
      val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream)
    val imgByte: ByteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()

    return android.util.Base64.encodeToString(imgByte, android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP )
}

override fun onActivityResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    resultCode: Int,
    data: Intent?
) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        val path: Uri? = data.data
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, path)
            profile?.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
}
```

well im getting crash from above code:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Part parameters using the MultipartBody.Part must not include a part name in the annotation. (parameter #7)

Comment: @Winni I Suggest you use multipart. Or try to compress image and extract that base64 to update the server.

Comment: @Venky i used compression in second method -->`bitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream` and also used multipart in second method

Comment: What is API end accepting ? - A multipart file or Base64 images

Comment: it is accepting token ,firstname,lastname,phone,dob,and profilepic @Venky

Comment: one Base64 image profile image @Venky

Comment: The compress it an send

Comment: @Venky i dont get it what you are saying

Comment: can you try to remove the naming part

 @Part profile_pic: MultipartBody.Part?

Comment: `naming part`? what should i remove in `@Part profile_pic: MultipartBody.Part?` @vikas

Comment: the string inside the Part("profile_pic") just send make it like above i posted

Comment: in short part can't have the string just remove from all the fields

Comment: getting crash in log--> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Part annotation must supply a name or use MultipartBody.Part parameter type. (parameter #2)

Comment: @vikaskumar getting crahed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to change something like below since all you are sending string so multipart file won't be ideal. just send it using request body let's see how server responds.

```
@Multipart
@POST("update")
fun useredit(
    @Header("access_token") token: String,
    @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> partMap
):Call<LoginResponse>
```

and wherever you are calling do like this.

```
// create a map of data to pass along
RequestBody first_name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),"your name here"); 
RequestBody last_name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),"your last name here");
RequestBody email = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),"your email here");
RequestBody dob = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),"your dob here");
RequestBody phone_no = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),"your phone no here");
RequestBody profile_pic = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),"your picture base64 string here");
    
Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();  
map.put("first_name", first_name);  
map.put("last_name", last_name);  
map.put("email", email);
map.put("dob", dob);
map.put("phone_no", phone_no);
map.put("profile_pic", profile_pic);
```

and then pass it to the calling function

```
 RetrofitClient.instance.useredit(token, map)//some code follows
```

**Edit:**

also need to send the image base64 in correct format like

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQ.........
```

or convert it to base64 encoding by using following method.

```
private fun convertToString(): String? {
val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
bitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat. JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream)
val imgByte: ByteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()

return android.util.Base64.encodeToString(imgByte, android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP )
}
```

change your map from java to kotlin implementation as shown below in the code

```
val map: MutableMap<String, RequestBody> = HashMap() 
map["first_name"] = first_name
map["last_name"] = last_name
map["email"] = email
map["dob"] = dob
map["phone_no"] = phone_no
map["profile_pic"] = profile_pic
```

Comment: also clear the air on if the server accepts base64 string or file itself.

Comment: if server accepts file then you need to change the part for profile_picture to Multipart.Part

Comment: made the change remove the () from @PartMap

Comment: now error at map-->  RetrofitClient.instance.useredit(token, map)

Comment: saying required Map<> found hashmap<>

Comment: made the change make it to Map instead of HashMap

Comment: Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218806/discussion-between-vikas-kumar-and-wini).

Comment: Thanks Buddy your answer help me for video uploading.